# Does the view_search_results event capture only internal searches?

Tags: google-analytics-4

Does site search tracking (`view_search_results` event) track *only* internal site searches?

Client of mine has product autosuggest search on their site but it looks like not many users are actually clicking on autosuggest terms - it looks like most of them are just entering search terms and clicking search button. If this is the case we need to rethink the internal search since obviously nobody is using it as intended.

Unless this event is also tracking non-internal searches somehow and counts some organic or other traffic?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

View Search Results event only count the number of internal searches with corresponding parameters you defined in the site search section .